# How should I structure this loop?

Tags: loops, readability

From time to time, I run into loops like this one, where I'm not sure how it should be structure to both avoid code repetition and make it most readable.

*Please note that while in this example I write in C# and use Unity3d engine, this question is about the loops in general and there's nothing specific about C#/Unity3d here, or so it would seem to me.*

```
    // ...

    Vector3 rayPosition  = transform.position;
    Vector3 rayDirection = transform.forward;

    RaycastHit hit;

    Vector3 rayFinish = rayPosition + rayDirection * rangeLeft; // This line repeats...

    while (Physics.Linecast ( rayPosition, rayFinish, out hit ) ) {

        rangeLeft -= hit.distance;

        rayPosition = hit.point;
        rayDirection = Vector3.Reflect(rayDirection, hit.normal);

        rayFinish = rayPosition + rayDirection * rangeLeft; // ...here.

    }

    // ...
```

(Of course, this code repeating is trivial and small, but it's just an example.)

It's not possible to make it into do...while loop, because the condition needs to be checked before first run of the loop. What's the best way to write code like this?

Answer (score 0):

A do-while loop is a little tricky, since the test is a method that needs to be called before the body of the loop. The code below removes the duplication, but I'm not sure how much it helps the readability.

```
while (true) { 
  Vector3 rayFinish = rayPosition + rayDirection * rangeLeft;

  if (!Physics.Linecast ( rayPosition, rayFinish, out hit ))
      break;

    rangeLeft -= hit.distance;

    rayPosition = hit.point;
    rayDirection = Vector3.Reflect(rayDirection, hit.normal);
}
```

This might be a bit more readable:

```
bool linecastGood = true;

while (linecastGood) { 
  Vector3 rayFinish = rayPosition + rayDirection * rangeLeft;

  linecastGood = Physics.Linecast ( rayPosition, rayFinish, out hit )

  if (linecastGood) 
  {
    rangeLeft -= hit.distance;
    rayPosition = hit.point;
    rayDirection = Vector3.Reflect(rayDirection, hit.normal);
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually, I had the first variant before, and then refactored it to this. Isn't loop while(true) always considered a bad practice?

The second one avoids code duplication, but in my opinion, it's less readable — you have to scan code at least twice to understand what it's doing.

Comment: @golergka: I agree that while(true) should be avoided, which is why I thought version #2 might be more readable. I just edited it to make the intent a little more explicit (IMO), but it's still not great. The fundamental issue is that you want to use one call for both a necessary calculation in the middle of the loop body, but also use its return value as the loop condition. Loop conditions only come at the beginning or the end, so I don't see any choice other than to either save the value and use it in the while condition, or use it to break out of the middle of the loop. Or use a goto...